# How to generate random numbers from range without zero

Tags: c

This is my function

```
int nepresnost_N2(int S){

    int N2, N2_1, N2_2; 
    N2_1 = -S/10;
    N2_2 = S/10;    
    N2 = rand() % (N2_2 + 1 - N2_1) + N2_1; 
    printf("%i", N2);

}
```

I dont know how to make conditions for (without 0).
Any ideas, thanks :)

Comment: `nepresnost_N2(int S)` need to work for large `S` values?  Values above `RAND_MAX/2` oblige multiple calls to `rand()`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want drawings to be in the range `[a, b]` excluding zero, then generate a random number in `[a, b - 1]` and add 1 to it if the returned value is non-negative.

That will have superior statistical properties to sampling and rejecting `0` values.

Comment: @olibub: I had some trouble understanding your notation, so I generalised it.

Comment: Do you have some information why it would be different from just rejecting 0 values? The only advantage I see is that you never need to run the generator more than once for one output value.

Comment: The "superior statistical properties" claim is incorrect and misguided. The exclusion method is quite common with pseudorandom number generation, and is based on the fact that excluding values or ranges does not affect the distribution outside those values or ranges at all. I hope @Bathsheba will remove it, because it will only confuse learners, and possibly even lead them away from using the exclusion method. Which would be extremely counterproductive.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: I'll try to dig out a paper to refute your claim later on in the day. I am correct when it comes to linear congruential random number generators. I think there are also some words on this in the old classic "Numerical Recipes in Fortran".

Comment: @Bathsheba: No, you are not correct, because you are not referring to any specific method of limiting the range (in particular, the modulo operator, which is the method discussed in Numerical Recipes IIRC). Feel free to dig out the references, but do read them first yourself.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I'm still waiting for your refuttal, or editing of your misleading answer. I even checked out the Random Numbers chapter NRinF90, and found nothing remotely like your assertions. There is nothing inherent in LCGs either that would make a zero *output* special. (While many PRNGs, not just LCGs, need to avoid zero as an internal state, that is an unrelated detail). Is your "reputation" or "face" that much more important to you, than helping others learn?

Answer (score 5):

Since your range has both a negative and a positive side, going from `-s` to `+s`, you can shorten the positive part of the range by 1, then add 1 in case when the generated value is non-negative:

```
N2_1 = -S/10;
N2_2 = S/10-1; // Shrink by one    
N2 = rand() % (N2_2 + 1 - N2_1) + N2_1;
if (N2 >= 0) { // Correct for zero
    N2++;
}
```

Alternatively you could check the result for zero, and generate a new number if necessary:

```
int nepresnostNoZero(int S) {
    int res;
    do {
        res = nepresnost_N2(S);
    } while (res == 0);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: @olibub if its working for you then mark as answer because other members may still work to solve this problem so mark it as answer if its  working as your correct solution thanks